# URL is adding the root folder

Tags: redirect, apache2, directory, virtualhost

I'm using Ubuntu Server with Apache2 to host my websites.

I have two domains, www.test.com and www.domain.com (not real names)

Inside of my sites-available I have the default that is pointed to my www.test.com domain and then I have a created one for www.domain.com inside that I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.com
ServerAlias domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/domainfolder
<Directory />
Options +FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now the website works, I can navigate to it and use it but since I'm using it for wordpress when ever I click on say Admin CP it will try to navigate to www.domain.com/domainfolder/admin-cp/ I'm just not sure why it's trying to access the folder it's stored in?

Using .htaccess just gives me an internal server error because it's always going down a directory, here is the code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)folder 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domainfolder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Does the wordpress config know that it's installed in `/var/www/domainfolder` and not `/var/www` ?

Comment: How would I check? I copied the installation files to the root folder "/var/www/domainfolder" and went to my URL as I did with my other domain and it is adding the folder to the URL.

Comment: I checked wp-config.php and it's set to define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');